# WPF Scrollviewer + Grid + MinWidth

Tags: wpf, xaml

Consider the following grid column layout:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
<ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200" Width="*" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
<ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200" Width="*" />
```

What I want is to basically activate a horizontal `ScrollViewer` only when the width becomes less than the combined `Width`s of all columns with regards to the `Auto`/`MinWidth` columns. For example, if the `Auto` `Width` columns were both 100, the `ScrollViewer` should activate when the `Width` of the `Grid` becomes less than (100 + 200 + 100 + 200)

Is there any way to create this kind of layout without handling size changes events?

Comment: Do you mean when user resizes the `Window` and the `Grid` is loaded you want then the `ScrollViewer` to become visible?

Comment: @XAMlMAX Yes; but the ScrollViewer should only be visible when the Width of the Grid is below the minimum width.

Comment: So, I take it that currently it's appearing even though current width is greater than the minimum one?

Comment: When a ScrollViewer is active with horizontal scrolling enabled in a star-width Grid, the star-width behaves like auto-width (stopping text from wrapping for example)

Comment: The star-width behaves like auto-width? Is your grid wrapped in a `StackPanel` by any chance?

Comment: @XAMlMAX It is contained in a ScrollViewer; similar to a Horizontal StackPanel in the sense that it gives the Grid infinite Width.